# C++. Avoiding cross-linking in multple files project

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I've been building many C++ projects for my university recently. They were consisted of multiple files with one Makefile. All in a ***prj*** folder with Makefile within, the source files in ***src*** folder and headers in ***inc*** folder. Makefile compiled it to object files in ***obj*** folder and than linked it to the final program.

I do got many strange errors which I broke down into that, e.g. I've included *Matrices.h* in *Vector.h* file and *Vector.h* in a *Matrix.h*. The compiler than said that some methods do not exist in a *Matrix* class.

I have to include *Vector.h* in *Matrix.h*. Then, include Matrix in *main.cpp*. I use *sqrt()* and *pow()* functions in all files.

Now I wonder is it proper to avoid declaring continously <*cmath*> library in *Vector.h*, then *Matrix.h* and finally in *main.cpp*? I'd rather just declare it in *Vector.h* and leave it. The complier is g++ and its Linux Debian.

I use preprocessor directives:

```html
#ifndef VECTOR_HH //or MATRIX_HH etc.
#define VECTOR_HH

#include <cmath>

//class body


#endif`
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c) might help you resolve situations like this.

Comment: That definitely helped a bit. However, what I particularly meant, was if I include library in a file that is included in another file, do I need to include that library again if the latter file uses functions from that library. Is it correct, if I omit it, since it is included in the include file?

Comment: Yes, you can safely omit any files that are already included.

Comment: Is it a good practice?

Comment: I would say it is common practice, but I can't give you a well-founded answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice is to define a generic header file, where you can include all the necessary header files at one, along with header guards.

Consider for example `common-hdr.h` wherein you declare

```
#ifndef COMMON-HDR_HH
#include <cmath>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "Matrix.h"

// other common files

#endif
```

Now you free to include just `common-hdr.h` to all files.

Answer (score 0):

To be independent of #include changes in included files, you should include-what-you-use.

Comment: So I should include, e.g. <cmath> library wherever I use one of its functions, regardless of included custom headers, should I?